# How to properly extend a database model with PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns

I know that the title of this question is not intuitive, but let's go to the question.

I've designed a "core system" for all my backend web apps (control panels, systems to manage clientes, balances, etc). This "core" is the start point for developing new modules according to the new system specific needs, but I always keep the "core modules":

- Users (to manage user roles)
- User type (in distinct systems there are distinct kinds of users, so it's nice to manage them dinamicly)
- Modules (to create new modules and add permissions to them)
- Dashboard

My main question is for the User module. Since it has the default columns

- UserId; Name; Login; e-Mail; Password; isRoot; isPowerUser; UserTypeId

I want to create new control panels and apps, but dont want to change this table to keep the "core" updatable with an easy process in the future. My ideia of design is to create table named User_Extra which will contai all the extra columns for this specific user.

Is this a good approach? I'll also will create a new class named UserExtra.class.php.

If u want to take a look at the project to get the ideia: https://bitbucket.org/alexandrekop/akop-core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine looking at your database schema, and seeing a table named "user_extra" with a bunch of fields that aren't related to each other in any way and each field is related to a different module, does it feel 'right'?

My suggestion is to split the extra fields into relevant tables, possibly per module, or per logical group.

For example, if one module was related to addresses, you would have a table "user_addresses", with things only specific to the address of the user.

Comment: Great! Makes a lot of sense!